# Como pegar o valor com getElement e atribuir a uma variável?

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse código onde estou pegando os valores de forma correta do formulário (fiz um `alert` com cada item e estáa pegando certo). Só que na hora de salvar na variável a soma não da certo, qdo dou `alert` em soma aparece `NaN`. Segue o trecho do meu código:

```
function somaPesos() {
    var soma = 0;
    var itens = document.getElementsByClassName("soma");

    for (i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
        var item = parseInt(itens[i].value);
        alert(item);
        soma = soma + item;
    }

    alert(soma);    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Testei o teu código e parece-me que esta correto: http://jsfiddle.net/d47yxjn3/1/

Comment: Há aqui uma coisa que não estou a entender... Se estás a dar o alert do teu item ao percorrer o ciclo for, onde está mais especificamente o erro? É a calcular a soma?

Comment: Testei aqui também obtendo o valor através do html, para verificar se o problema era esse e tudo funciona como esperado, você só tem que preencher todos os campos, senão o erro ocorre como você citou. Verifique o [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/ooLmdgx3/1/).

Comment: Penso que o problema seja mesmo esse que estás a indicar @Fernando

Comment: Como você está obtendo os valores a partir de um seletor de class (que é um pouco arriscado), pode ser que sua class = "soma", esteja sendo utilizada em algum lugar que você não espera e o valor esta vindo vazio/undefined, verifique se isto não esta acontecendo? (ou se isso não está a acontecer? como diria o @CesarMiguel, hehe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse erro provavelmente está ocorrendo porque algum input que contém a classe "soma" está sem valor. Você pode fazer uma verificação antes, para isso não ocorrer mais.

```js
function somaPesos() {
  var soma = 0;
  var itens = document.getElementsByClassName("soma");

  for (i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(itens[i].value))) {
      var item = parseInt(itens[i].value);
      soma += item;
    }
  }

  alert(soma);
  return false;
}
```

```html
Valor 1: <input type="text" class="soma"><br>
Valor 2: <input type="text" class="soma"><br>
Valor 3: <input type="text" class="soma">
<input type="button" onclick="somaPesos()" value="Somar">
```

O que eu fiz fui dar um parse pra Int no input, pois vazio a função IsNaN retorna false e depois neguei para ele e entrar e atribuir o valor para soma.

Comment: Era isso mesmo gente! Obrigado a todos que responderam.

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function somaPesos(){
            var soma = 0;

            var itens = document.getElementsByClassName("soma");
            for(i = 0; i < itens.length; i++){
                if(!isNaN(itens[i].value)){
                   var item = parseInt(itens[i].value);
                   alert(item);
                   soma = soma + item;
                }                 
            }
            alert(soma);

            return false;
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No html :

```
<input id="ipTexto" type="text"></input>
```

No Js:

```
var inputText = document.getElementById('ipTexto');
```

Neste ponto, inputText tem o elemento inteiro. Caso precise do valor, use :

```
console.log(inputText.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Este erro `NaN` (Not a Number) acontece quando você tenta fazer uma operação ( `+` pode ser uma concatenação) com uma variável que não é número.

Provavelmente você não digitou algum número na `input` e então ele tenta somar um número com alguma coisa.

Comment: parece-me que o erro não passa na forma como o alert esta a tratar a variável

Comment: Em qual browser se tem esse problema com alert @Earendul?

Comment: Corrigi minha resposta. Sorry pela falha.